# Cakephp 3: Getting Forbidden error when going to edit in live server

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

This code working fine in local server but in live server I am getting  Forbidden error 403. If I mention form type = 'post' it's working in server. but file not uploading. If I use 'type'=>'file' then getting  Forbidden error. Here is my form code

```
<?php 
     echo $this->Form->create($depositOption,['type'=>'file']); // type='post' is working but image not uploading 
     echo $this->Form->input('name');
     echo $this->Form->input('image_edit',['type'=>'file']);
     echo $this->Form->submit("Submit")
     echo $this->Form->end() 
?>
```

My controller code like

```
if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
    if(!empty($this->request->data['image_edit']['name'])){
        // upload image code 
    }
}
$depositOption = $this->DepositOptions->patchEntity($depositOption, $this->request->data);
$this->DepositOptions->save($depositOption)
```

How to define this form type is file also type is post.

Comment: Have you enable your debug mode ?

Comment: My 'debug' => false

Comment: Plz enable it and again check.you can get error.

Comment: Here from is not sending to controller, I have debugged in controller it's not sending from if I use type = file. It may apache permission issue. It may I have to do something in htaccess, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try this ? Add enctype using form option

```
<?= $this->Form->create($depositOption,['type'=>'post','enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) ?>
```

Comment: This doesn't really make any sense as an answer, because [that's exactly what `'type' =>  'file'` does](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/View/Helper/FormHelper.php#L401-L403), i.e. it's not changing anything.

Comment: Actually I know that type = file send data in post method , but I given this ans because she mention type='post' is working , but if she use type = 'file' it's not working. So I think keep type = "post" and add enctype in options so it may worked. Actually I faced same problem few months ago. I don't know this code has been work for me.

Comment: @AD7six This ans is working for me, Please see evidence https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddFTJuQCli4&feature=youtu.be

Comment: @SatuSultana just look at the page source for the two forms. Either they are the same, or they aren't (and the difference would help explain why one works and one doesn't). Working around something like this instead of actually identifying and fixing the root cause, is not a good idea. Also `Getting Forbidden error when going to edit in live server` is unclear _show_ the error message when asking a question, your video clearly shows an apache error page - i.e. CakePHP is not responsible for your problem but something in your apache config. It shouldn't require watching a video to see that.

Comment: I'm running cakephp3.6.  The default baked form->create wasn't working in edit forms in my production server (everything OK in dev). Changed it and now it's working. Thanks!